# Cannot build the Rocket.Chat.Android: fails at task ':app:compileSdk'

Tags: android, rocket.chat

When attempting to build the app it fails during build with the error

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileSdk'.
>
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

This happens only after a Git Bash window pops ups with what looks like the start of the output from the build-sdk.sh script.

This happens when using both Android Studios `Run > Run app` and the command `./gradlew assembleDebug`. I have built the sdk and the generated files are located in app/libs.

I am using the develop branch of Rocket.Chat.Android,the latest version of Android Studio Preview, and my gradle version is 4.9.

Why is this happening and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I have opened an issue on their github, full stack trace can be found there as well: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Android/issues/1704

Comment: So what you want dude ?

Comment: Preferably some help as to why this is happening and if there's a known fix

Comment: Try Clean Project or rerun gradle with --info like how the logs suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of an outdated version of Git Bash (Git for Windows).

After updating to the latest version (`version 2.19.0.windows.1`) I can compile and run the app